# Estimating error in Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider the nth order Taylor polynomial for cos x centered at 0 dented T(n) (x,0). How larger must we take n to guarantee that the error |cos x-T(n) (x,0) |is at most 10^-3 for x in [-pi/2,pi/2)

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed but ... all i have written down is |cosx-{1-x^2/2!+.....x^n/n!}| i have no clue how to continue

Answer (score 2):

So, this uses the [Remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), which I suggest you check out. First, observe that any derivative of $\cos x$ is bounded between $1$ and $-1$ (they are all plus or minus sine or cosine). Then, we know that 
$$
|R_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}(x-0)^{n+1} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
$$
On the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ this is maximized at $-\pi/2$, so 
$$
|R_n(x)| \leq \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}~~~~\text{for $x\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2)$}
$$
Now, we plug in values of $n$ until $|R_n(x)|<10^{-3}$. It appears that at $n=7$ we have $|R_7(x)|<0.000919$.

Comment: You mean maximized at $x=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, since $\cos(x)$ is an alternating series, then you can use the fact that the remainder of alternating series is given by

> $$ |R_n|\leq a_{n+1},$$

which gives you the desired $n=3$.

Comment: Better. I've overlooked this too many times. :P

Comment: @Alec: Since it is an alternating series, then it is easier to use this form for estimating the error. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I know. I remember getting screwed over in first year calculus on an exam trying to use remainder theorem on $e^{-x^2}$ instead of alternating series theorem.

Comment: @Alec: You mean $e^{-x^2}$. So, already you've got an experience.

Comment: Sorry but $\cos(x)$ is an alternating series (with respect to the variable $x^2$) only when $|x|\leqslant\sqrt2$. For general values of $x$, the series "becomes alternated", so to speak, only after a few terms, namely, when $(2n+2)(2n+1)\geqslant x^2$.

Comment: so how should i be approaching it i am confused